# How set The table cell should be the same width for the whole table except for the first column cells

Tags: html, css

[Highlighted cells should be same width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKkYs.png)

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="tg-baqh" colspan="5">Graduate People</th>
      <th class="tg-baqh" colspan="4">Uneducated People</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">City</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Male</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Female</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Trangender</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Total</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Male</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Female</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Trangender</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">Total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Delhi</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">3000</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">3000</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">200</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">6200</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">1000</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">1000</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">100</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">2200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="tg-0lax">Mumbai</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">4000</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">4000</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">500</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">8500</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">1400</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">600</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">50</td>
      <td class="tg-baqh">2050</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I used "table-layout: fixed;" but not get the expected output. Cell content should be the same width as per the transgender data cell.